# Calendar Permissions - Edit/Delete

Tags: permissions, calendar

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to give a user permissions to edit/delete calendar events but nothing else.

For this I created a new group, and that group has only one permission level attached. And I have a user who has only a member of this group.

I've gone through the permissions you can add to the level, and the only ones that seem to enable the user to edit/delete the calender entries are:

- Manage Web Site  -  Grants the ability to perform all administration
  tasks for the Web site as well as manage content.
- Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web
  Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint
  Foundation-compatible editor.

The problem obviously, is that I kind of need a more granular version of these levels. Also they work together, you can't have Manage Web Site on it's own.

I know I'm doing something wrong, I can't be the only person to ever get this request right?

I've seenn solutions where you deny all access to edit pages to the pages library, and then divy page edit permissions but don't really see how that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create yourself an event handler and a custom permission, add the user the custom permission and on deletion if the user has this permission to perform the task.

User ItemDeleting [(Look here for basically what you need)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/272bf02e-5ada-4d0f-bd23-fd6ca2fe9380) for the event and check the current users permissions for the site context and the object that they are deleting.

There is no OOTB permission for this.

Comment: Thanks for this.
In the end we have gone for a different, possibly more hacky approach. Although, I think I've confused myself and the fix I've come up with doesn't seem to fit with the question I originally asked. We enabled the DisplayRibbon Toolbar in the DispForm.aspx of the calendar list, then i manually overrode the defaulttemplates of that toolbar to hide the manage permissions. It's a quick and dirty solution, but its doing the job (for now). SharePoint has mashed my head over the last few months so sorry if this post makes no sense, but thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 0):

SatBav,

You should be able to create a new permissions level in which the only permissions granted are the

- 'Edit Items'
- 'Delete Items'
- 'View Items'

list permissions along with any others you'd like them to still have on the calendar but leave 'Add Items' unchecked. Then give the calendar unique permissions and grant your groups your new permission level only. That should allow them to view, modify, and delete but not add any events (items in a list).